# Converting char to varchar columns increases database size

Tags: sql-server

I have a database (SQL Server 2005) with thousands of char columns. I want to convert these columns to varchar, 
then I follow this steps:

1. Shrink Database
2. Check the current stats, general and detailed (each table).
3. Massive conversion from char(x) to varchar(x)
4. Massive trim to the updated columns
5. Shrink Database
6. Check the current stats, general and detailed (each table).

For point 2 and 6 I run this query:

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0)
EXEC sp_spaceused --to check the current stats
SELECT --to check detailed stats
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
```

The problem is the size of the database after conversion (17062.50 MB) is considerably greater than the size before conversion (14975.13 MB).

If I make the comparison in a table with many varchar fields we can see more clearly:

```
         RowCounts     TotalSpaceKB     UsedSpaceKB     UnusedSpaceKB
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Before       77427            46440           45864               576
After        77427            85224           84664               560
```

The average column size for this table is:

```
Type         Average size (Sum(Len)/Count(*))
---------------------------------------------
varchar(12)                             11.05
varchar(100)                             1.97
varchar(12)                              3.29
varchar(70)                              3.84
varchar(150)                            32.54
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 14975.13 MB is not considerably greater than 17062.50 MB. The old fixed width columns stay in the row until [you rebuild the table though](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/02/19/why-should-i-rebuild-a-table-after-dropping-or-adding-a-column/)

Comment: You're right, both in my question (edited, poorly explained) and the rebuild. We performed a re-indexing and now the data is correct, the database is 20% lower, thanks!